# Show bootstrap Humburger on middle devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to show humburger on 990px width instead of 768. I tried this code in style sheet

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) { .collapse {
   display: none !important; }}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

`@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) {.collapse {display: inline !important; }}`

Then you set `display:none;` style to the element that contains the Hamburger menu.

E.g.: `<span class="collapse" style="display:none;">Hamburger menu</span>`